How can I put a mandatory sequence of Jobs in the food packing example?
I'm new to this and I've done an example to plan operations for a shoe manufacturing order, and I'm following the example of food packing, I've already made some changes to be able to put in a mandatory sequence of operations, but the algorithm isn't working. to behave correctly, is there an example that can help me with this issue of the sequence of operations.
Is this example

